# Java - How do I initialise an array holding items of type T in the constructor of a templated class?

Tags: java, arrays, templates, constructor

Searching this only found answers in C++, which I know plenty well already, but how do I do this in Java? I found answers that suggest I need to do the following:

```
class FixedArray<T> {

    public FixedArray(byte size) {
        array = new T[size];
    }

    private T[] array;
}
```

... but I get the error

```
Type parameter 'T' cannot be instantiated directly
```

Comment: @SukhpalSingh You're right, thanks for pointing me to the answer

Answer (score 2):

Actually `T` is not any data type but just a representative for `Generics` so you need to initialize a general `Object[]` array and cast it to `Generic Type T`,

Try this:

```
class FixedArray<T> {
public FixedArray(byte size) {
    array = (T[]) new Object[size];
}

private T[] array;
}
```

so for instance, you need to have an integer array it will be equivalent to:

```
Integer[] array = (Integer[]) new Object[size];
```